# Why isn't my event listener working inside the function?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, addeventlistener, slideshow

I have a function that makes a slideshow in JavaScript. While trying to add a feature, changing the slide with fade on click, my function stopped working, what is wrong with it? Complete code [on Khan Academy](https://en.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/js-library-exatreojs-slideshow-library/2950604004)

```js
var slideShow = function(container, time, effect) {
  container = document.querySelector(container);
  this.images = [];
  this.curImage = 0;

  if (effect === "click_fade") {
    for (i = 0; i < container.childElementCount; i++) {
      this.images.push(container.children[i]);
      this.images[i].style.opacity = 0;
    }

    // Handle going to to the next slide
    var nextSlideClick = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.images.length; i++) {
        if (i != this.curImage) this.images[i].style.opacity = 0;
      }
      this.images[this.curImage].style.opacity = 1;
      this.curImage++;
      if (this.curImage >= this.images.length) this.curImage = 0;
      window.setTimeout(nextSlide.bind(document.getElementById(this)), time);
    };
    container.addEventListener("click", nextSlideClick)

  }

  nextSlide.call(this);

};
slideShow("#slideshow", 2000, "click_fade");
```

```css
.slide {
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
  <img class="slide" src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/animals/birds_rainbow-lorakeets.png" alt="Rainbow lorakeets" />
  <img class="slide" src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/animals/butterfly.png" alt="Butterfly" />
  <img class="slide" src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/animals/cat.png" alt="Cat" />
  <img class="slide" src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/animals/crocodiles.png" alt="Crocodiles" />
  <img class="slide" src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/animals/fox.png" alt="Fox" />

</div>
```

No result, what is wrong?

Comment: It might be better to indicate precisely what you changed, what specifically does/doesn't happen, and what debugging steps you've taken. I'm always wary of wanton `this` usage, particularly wrt handler functions run later that refer to `this`.

Comment: edited it, go here? https://en.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/js-library-exatreojs-slideshow-library/2950604004

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
<style>
   .slide {
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
</style>

<div id="slideshow">
     <img class="slide" src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/animals/birds_rainbow-lorakeets.png" alt="Rainbow lorakeets" />
    <img class="slide" src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/animals/butterfly.png" alt="Butterfly" />
   <img class="slide" src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/animals/cat.png" alt="Cat" />
   <img class="slide" src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/animals/crocodiles.png" alt="Crocodiles" />
   <img class="slide" src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/animals/fox.png" alt="Fox" />
</div>

<script>
    var slideShow = function(container, time, effect) {
    container = document.querySelector(container);
    this.images = [];
    this.curImage = 0;

  if (effect === "click_fade") {
  for (i = 0; i < container.childElementCount; i++) {
        this.images.push(container.children[i]);
        this.images[i].style.opacity = 0;
    }

    // Handle going to to the next slide
    var nextSlideClick = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.images.length; i++) {
            if (i != this.curImage) this.images[i].style.opacity = 0;
      }
        this.images[this.curImage].style.opacity = 1;
        this.curImage++;
        if (this.curImage >= this.images.length) this.curImage = 0;
    window.setTimeout(nextSlideClick.bind(document.getElementById(this)), time);
        };
        container.addEventListener("click", nextSlideClick)

  nextSlideClick.call(this);
}
};
slideShow("#slideshow", 2000, "click_fade");
</script>
```

Made some minor changes in this jsfiddle : [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/gummiah/a6s15wzq/)

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle to my answer

Comment: but it works automatically though, the click doesn't do anything

Comment: That is because "this" doesn't have a value when you click the container. You need to save that in a varible that is outside of the slideshow function block. I've updated the jsfiddle with a solution.

Comment: thx a lot! Is it possible to not make them slide automatically though? sorry if I'm giving you a hard time

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Here's an solution of slideshow on click https://jsfiddle.net/gummiah/8094k13e/  I would recommend using jquery for this. Lot less code.